# DomDocument removeChild in foreach reindexing the dom

Tags: javascript, php, html, dom, domdocument

I am trying to delete `p` tags with `data-spotid` attribute

```
        $dom = new DOMDocument();
        @$dom->loadHTML($description);
        $pTag = $dom->getElementsByTagName('p');

        foreach ($pTag as $value) {
            /** @var DOMElement $value */
            $id = $value->getAttribute('data-spotid');
            if ($id) {
                $value->parentNode->removeChild($value);
            }
        }
```

but when i am removing child it is reindexing the dom. let suppose i have 8 items i deleted 1st it will reindex it and 2nd element will become 1st and it will not delete it will go to 2nd which is now 3rd element.

Comment: I don't think "reindex" is quite the right term. It sounds like the foreach iterator isn't able to "rewind" itself (so to speak) to always be on the most current item in the loop if that loop gets manipulated. So it might be a more general referencing issue than something specific to `DomDocument`.

Comment: Seems like my hunch has some merit: http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.removechild.php#90292

Comment: You can use [`iterator_to_array($pTag)`](https://secure.php.net/manual/function.iterator-to-array.php). Demo: https://3v4l.org/ieN3X

Comment: @Yoshi - That's a pretty neat sandbox site. It looks like running two loops (one where you build the array of child elements, another where you remove the child elements from their parent) has consistently better performance results across versions, compared to your original demo or similar code that uses `iterator_to_array` to create an array variable first and then passing that variable into the foreach loop.

Comment: @Yoshi - With `iterator_to_array` but above `foreach` : https://3v4l.org/5ug9c ; With two `foreach` loops to get the children and then remove them : https://3v4l.org/dJiPA

Comment: @Anthony Sure, `iterator_to_array` creates the full array, and one should be aware of that. But unless we're talking about thousands of dom nodes, that's really not a performance problem, I wouldn't care too much about it. This way the code is succinct and easy to read. Honestly, the better optimization would be to just select the appropriate nodes, instead of all and then filtering them *by hand*. ;) For example: https://3v4l.org/tvNVe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is mentioned in a couple of comments on the [`DomNode::removeChild`](http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.removechild.php) documentation, with the issue apparently being how the iterator pointer on the foreach not being able to deal with the fact that you are removing items from a parent array while looping through the list of children (or something).

The recommended fix is to loop through the main node first and push the child nodes you want to delete to its own array, then loop through that "to-be-deleted" array and deleting those children from their parent. Example:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($description);
$pTag = $dom->getElementsByTagName('p');

$spotid_children = array();

foreach ($pTag as $value) {
    /** @var DOMElement $value */
    $id = $value->getAttribute('data-spotid');
    if ($id) {
        $spotid_children[] = $value; 
    }
}

foreach ($spotid_children as $spotid_child) {
    $spotid_child->parentNode->removeChild($spotid_child); 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use like this:

```
        $dom = new DOMDocument();
        @$dom->loadHTML($description);
        $pTag = $dom->getElementsByTagName('p');
        $count = count($pTag)
        for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
            /** @var DOMElement $value */
            $value = $pTag[$i];
            $id = $value->getAttribute('data-spotid');
            if ($id) {
                $i--;$count--;
                $value->parentNode->removeChild($value);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Like I commented, the *easy* solution would be to just *cast* the iterator to an array. E.g.:

```
$elements = iterator_to_array($elements);
```

But, if we're talking about performance, a better way would be to simply  select only the required nodes. Neat side-effect, the removal-problem also goes away.

E.g.:

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$doc->loadXML(<<<__XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <element>1</element>
    <element attr="a">2</element>
    <element>3</element>
    <element>4</element>
    <element attr="a">5</element>
    <element attr="a">6</element>
    <element>7</element>
    <element>8</element>
</root>
__XML
);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$elements = $xpath->query('//element[@attr]');

foreach ($elements as $element) {
    $element->parentNode->removeChild($element);
}

echo $doc->saveXML();
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/CM9Fv

Comment: This is a solid solution, but requires two things that may not be possible : 1) that the targeted elements can be selected via XPath (this may not be the case if the elements needing to be removed are based on zany logic, like "if child element attribute1='x' and attribute2>=7" or worse), and 2) that the amount of effort to figure out whether an XPath will work to find the one that does (if there is one) is realistic compared to other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

( Assuming that the **$dom** contains the (DOM) paragraphs you need to filter out ).
Let's try some good old JavaScript:

```
$ptag = $dom.all.tags("p");
$ptag = [].slice.call($ptag);
$i = 0; 
while($ptag[$i]){
'data-spotid' in $ptag[$i].attributes ? $ptag[$i++].outerHTML = "" : 0
}
```

NOTE:
I'm using outerHTML to destroy unwanted elements to avoid calling its parent and relocating the node of interest we already have. Recent Firefox versions are finally supporting it (11+).[MDN ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML)

I'm also using the brief *all.tags()* syntax for brevity; Firefox might not be supporting it yet, so you might want to fall back to 'getElementsByTagName()' call there.

Comment: To demystify your problem completely, we have to reveal the fact that you are working on a Live collection. Looping through, while removing  elements from a live dom collection while having linear growing index, will undoubtedly cause it to skip elements. That's why you need to convert it ($ptag live collection) to Static. That's what I did there.