# loop through DomDocument array only returns the even elements, not the odd elements

Tags: php, wordpress, domdocument

I'm trying to build and AMP valid theme for WordPress from scratch, and so I need to convert standard html elements like img and iframe to AMP valid ones.  I have a function that I found that selects the images by tag name and the goes through a foreach loop to get the attributes of each img tag and create the amp-img element. The problem is that it's only looping through the even elements, not the odd ones. For example, if the the content has 5 images in it, the function only loops through elements 0, 2 and 4. Elements 1 and 3 are not returned.

Here's the code:

```
function replace_image_and_attributes($the_content) {
    $post = new DOMDocument();
    $post->loadHTML($the_content);
    $imgs = $post->getElementsByTagName('img');
    
    //this var_dump returns 5
    var_dump($imgs);

    foreach($imgs as $img) {
        $src = $img->getAttribute('src');
        $width = $img->getAttribute('width');
        $height = $img->getAttribute('height');

        $wrapper = $post->createElement('amp-img');

        $wrapper->setAttribute('src', $src);
        $wrapper->setAttribute('width', $width);
        $wrapper->setAttribute('height', $height);
        $wrapper->setAttribute('layout', 'responsive');

        $img->parentNode->insertBefore($wrapper, $img);
        $img->parentNode->removeChild($img);
    };

    $the_content = $post->saveHTML();

return $the_content;
}

add_filter('the_content', 'replace_image_and_attributes', 99);
```

Does anybody know what can be happening?
Please if my explanation is not good let me know.
Thank you guys for your time =)

Comment: Can you provide the value of `$the_content`, exact recieved return and exact desired return?

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36911495/231316

Comment: It doesn't work because you use `removeChild` inside the loop. Save the `$img` into an array and then do a second loop to remove those elements.

Comment: Thank you guys! I read your answers and made an array with each img element and a second loop for removing the img element and It worked like a charm!